# HTTP live streaming standard with HTML5

Tags: html, http-live-streaming

What will be the standard for HTTP live streaming with HTML5?

Or what are the standards currently available? I know Apple HTTP streaming is one.

Answer (score 4):

There is no accepted standard yet at time of writing.

Apple's HTTP Live Streaming is the best candidate. Because of the iPad/iPhone it now has considerable support from content encoders (see [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Live_Streaming) for list), and is also supported in the Android 4 Video Player (but apparently not in Chrome mobile). Apple have [taken some steps](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-pantos-http-live-streaming) to have it ratified as an IETF standard. A number of the Flash video players are now supporting HLS as well as RTMP streaming, so you only need to package your content once.

[Microsoft's HTTP Smooth Streaming](http://www.iis.net/download/SmoothStreaming) is similar, but in practice support only exists in Silverlight. Adobe also have a HTTP streaming format ([HTTP Dynamic Streaming](http://www.adobe.com/products/hds-dynamic-streaming.html) / 'San Jose' streaming), but this is only supported in Flash. Either of these *could* be supported in browsers, if the will was there. Both are probably doomed.

Alternatively the MPEG group are sponsoring [MPEG-DASH](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_Adaptive_Streaming_over_HTTP), but one suspects in-the-field support for this is a way off.

Answer (score 3):

It'll be one the `HTTP` adaptive streaming protocols.

As of 2015, there are two main protocols, `HLS` and `DASH` (four if you also count `HDS` and `Smooth`).

`HLS` has a wide adoption (see the 2015 report here: http://info.encoding.com/delivery-report-2015.html) but less features than `DASH`.

There are two `DASH` flavors: [MPEG-DASH](http://dashif.org/) and [WebM-DASH](http://www.webmproject.org/), the latter based on the open format which is a subset of `Matroska`.

`DASH` is gaining momentum and it has a good chance of becoming the next industry standard. The choice for `HTML5`  will take into account the supported codecs and their licensing terms. Since `H.264/AVC` and `H.265/HEVC` are not free, `WebM` with `VP8`, `VP9` has a better chance.

[image]

Image source: https://www.bitcodin.com/blog/2015/03/mpeg-dash-vs-apple-hls-vs-microsoft-smooth-streaming-vs-adobe-hds/

Answer (score 1):

HLS is also playable in HTML5 if your browser supports MediaSource Extension, using hls.js library, which implements an HTTP Live Streaming client. It relies on HTML5 video and MediaSource Extensions for playback.
it works by transmuxing MPEG-2 Transport Stream into ISO BMFF (MP4) fragments.
hls.js does not need any player, it works directly on top of a standard HTMLelement.

you can find JS library and instructions here:
https://github.com/dailymotion/hls.js

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the container. Fragmented H.264 can contain live streams. It can be transmitted thru HTTP. Google's WebM can also be streamed over HTTP.

It is unlikely that HTML5 will add any delivery methods other than HTTP. So no RTP or UDP on the horizon.